# Angular 5: *ngIf="isValid;else other_content" VS *ngIf="isValid" . *ngIf="!isValid"

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

This question is about understanding why one technique is better than the other. In angular 4/5, inside a template you can achieve the same thing by doing:

**1) *ngIf-else syntax**

```
<div *ngIf="isValid;else other_content">
    content here ...
</div>

<ng-template #other_content>other content here...</ng-template>
```

**2) *ngIf="isValid"   *ngIf="!isValid"**

```
<div *ngIf="isValid">
  content here ...
</div>

<div *ngIf="!isValid">
 other content here...
</div>
```

The two syntax are perfectly valid, with the syntax 1, you can go a bit further like describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006550/how-to-use-ngif-else-in-angular), but is there any performance / best practice recommendations of using one versus the other ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ngIf - else vs two ngIf conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44682495/ngif-else-vs-two-ngif-conditions)

Comment: The main benefit I get from using the `else` syntax is that the template code is less repetitious. From a execution standpoint, I would think the if/else statement would be faster since it's only one evaluation versus two. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Indeed it is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44682495/ngif-else-vs-two-ngif-conditions, could not find this before my apologies

Comment: Duplicate question is closed and doesn't allow new answers to be added, so it shouldn't be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two `ngIf` directives are compiled twice and result in two bindings instead of one.

This becomes even more messy if the expression contains pipes:

```
<div *ngIf="isValidAsync | async">...</div>
<div *ngIf="!(isValidAsync | async)">...</div>
```

will result in two subscriptions.

`ngIf` else template is supported exactly to address this case and should be used as a rule of thumb.